# FAQ view - how to?

Tags: android

I have to do FAQ view on Android.My goal is how to accomplish this instead of code.I need to design a view as in the picture.[image]

What's the easiest way to do with android's components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a library, for example this one : [`ExpandableLayout`](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout), other is to do it manually.

This view is called `Expandable Layout`, so you can search an example for this in Google.

The idea is to create an `Adapter` which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, then as a parameter you receive a `List<String>` which are the list of headers, in your case is : What is Reddit?, What does the name "reddit" mean?, and so...

Then another parameter `private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;` this is every header will contain a `List<String>`

Important methods are :

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
```

Also

```
@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataHeader.get(i); //Remember to put the list Header here not the HashMap
}
```

And `getChildrenCount()`

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}
```

This is an example how you can create a stuff like this, rest you can search in Google, I gave enough information I guess :D

Let me know if something is unclear.